# Nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:14

Tags: nginx

Iam facing with this error,

Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:14
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=connlimit:10m;

    location /downloads {
    limit_conn connlimit 1;
    limit_rate 512k;
    }

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

What is wrong in this ?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69979261/2777965

Answer (score 1):

`location` directive can be used inside `server` and `location` directives. You have it inside `http` directive, which is not allowed.

Comment: Follow-up: if you get  "[emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here" next, that's because the `server` directive needs to be inside a `http` directive